# How to create 3d pcolormesh of array values?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data that occurs in an arrays at `x(0:127)`, `y(0:127)`, and `z(0:98)`. For example, at the coordinates of `x=23`, `y=27`, and `z=76` the data value might be 826. How can I create a 3d `pcolorrmesh` of these values to look similar to the link provided:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `pcolormesh` for 3D plots. However look [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) for the official matplotlib tutorial on 3D plottting.